# Soundcloud API - Adding/Removing Songs from Groups - 404 Error

Tags: soundcloud

I have been trying to use the Soundcloud API to add and remove songs from groups. I am using the soundcloud-python wrapper to enable me to do this easily.

I have got both Auth flows working correctly (either using OAuth2 or using user credentials directly), and I can use the python client to grab information about the logged in user etc. by performing calls as follows:

```
print client.get('/me').username
```

This indicates to me that I have correctly passed authorisation, and as I say, I have got this working via both methods.

My problem is when I try to make the following request which is provided as an example to add/remove songs from groups, I will always get a 404 error, whether or not the track already exists in the group (from the example off the Soundcloud API docs, under "Contributing Sounds to a Group"):

```
# contribute track to group
group = client.put('/groups/%d/contributions/%d' % (group.id, track.id))
```

If I perform any function on the /groups/{group-id}/contributions/{track-id} via the client object, I will always get a 404 error. If I am not authenticated I will get a 401 error. I have made 100% sure that I have used working group_id/track_id combinations by testing them through the API console, and hard-coding values where necessary to prove the operation.

This is what confuses me - if I use the same form of URI which failed with the python wrapper in the API Console (on the Soundcloud API website), and I am authenticated through OAuth, then the GET/PUT and DELETE all behave as expected on the same group_id's and track_id's which fail through the soundcloud-python wrapper.

Has anyone else had any issues with this? Have they got this working?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have just tried implementing a simple version using the Soundcloud Ruby SDK, and this behaves as expected (and has been observed through the Soundcloud API console). Therefore I believe this is an issue specifically with the Python SDK (soundcloud-python)

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error suggest that you are not authenticated. If that isn't the problem then, 
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading says (in "Contributing a Sound to a Group"):

...
Similarly, you can also remove contributions. (python example)

```
 import soundcloud

 # create a client object with access token
 client = soundcloud.Client(access_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')

 # delete track id 59 from group id 123
 client.delete('/groups/123/contributions/59')
```

Comment: That said, I've tried to write an example using just javascript, (well some jQuery as well) and it did not seem to work as expected from reading the developers guide, so I've added another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359227/)

Comment: A unauthenticated error normally returns as 401 I have found so far... I think this is an issue with the Python SDK, but I have never had a chance to look any further! I solved it by moving to Ruby.

Comment: And sorry for not responding - I didn't have email notifications turned on and never noticed the response! Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Don't worry about reply ;-) I too am now sure that it is a problem with the API example. Not sure if it will help you, but I've patched the Soundcloud javacript API example so that it _does_ work: [link](https://github.com/alexxroche/SoundCloud-API-jQuery-plugin) and some tests that I was playing with are over in: [link](https://github.com/alexxroche/AIF/tree/master/scripts/html/soundcloud).

Answer (score 0):

### Update

The pull request I link to below was accepted and merged into the API wrapper.

Just grab the updated source from Github, and this should be fixed.

*p.s. Sorry for the late update.*

---

The `/contributions` endpoint is buggy - see [this github issue](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/issues/21).

I've managed to hack the API to make this work until the bug is fixed on SoundCloud's side.
Make the following amendments to the <kbd>client.py</kbd> file:

```
def _resolve_resource_name(self, name):
    [...]
    name = name.rstrip('/').lstrip('/')
    if name[-13:] == 'contributions':
        return '%s%s/%s' % (self.scheme, self.host, name)
    return '%s%s/%s.json' % (self.scheme, self.host, name)
```

Or see [this pull request](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/pull/28).